# Make the web server Monkey generate a code 204 (No content)

Tags: android, html, cgi

I want to trick Android phones to believe they have access to Internet when connecting to my Wifi hotspot so that it will reconnect automatically next time.(for more info about that, check [this post](https://binfalse.de/2017/02/07/android-no-internet-access-detected-won-t-automatically-reconnect-aka-connected-no-internet/), I cannot use those solutions because I do not want to root the phone.)
To detect Internet access, Android requests the page:

```
connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204
```

If the webserver answers with code 200, Android offers to connect to a portal, that's not what I want.

So in the end, I need a way to generate the code 204, preferably using Monkey which is already installed on my target.
I activated the plugin cgi, and made it echo nothing, I also tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Status: 204 No Content"
echo ""
exit
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it. My syntax was wrong, I found the correct one in Monkey's code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content\r\n"
echo ""
exit
```